# Is it possible to alias array type in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, types, alias

I'm trying to do some serialization / deserialization stuff with a custom exception type. This type has a field defined as:

```
private object[] resourceMessageParams;
```

I've got all nice and strongly typed code with some Linq expression magic, but I want to go even further than that and do something like this:

```
using ResourceMessageParamsType = object[];//<-- "Identifier expected" error here
/*...*/
private ResourceMessageParamsType resourceMessageParams;
/*...*/
this.resourceMessageParams = 
    (ResourceMessageParamsType)serializationInfo.GetValue(
        ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(() => 
            resourceMessageParams), typeof(ResourceMessageParamsType));
```

Instead of this:

```
(object[])serializationInfo.GetValue(
    ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(() => 
        resourceMessageParams), typeof(object[]));
```

To accomodate for possible change of type of this field in the future, so one will have to change the type only once in alias definition. However, the compiler stops at `object` in `using ResourceMessageType = object[];` complaining that an identifier is expected. Changing to `Object[]` helps somewhat, but this time the bracket is highlighted with the same error message.

Is there a way to define an alias for array type in c#?

Comment: A general comment: it's redundant and generally bad form to put `Type` in the names of your types.

Comment: I have had the same issue regarding a Matrix alias class for a double[].

I ended up with using `Matrix = System.Collections.Generic.List<double>;` instead, and I am happy with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you can't "alias" array types.

You can work around it by encapsulating things in a `struct`, but that doesn't answer your question.

---

**Update:**

From the ECMA standard,

> *using-alias-directive:*
>
> `using` *identifier* = *namespace-or-type-name* ;

which clearly doesn't say anything about arrays being permitted.

(See page 100 for how *namespace-or-type-name* is defined.)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question asked. Have you got a proof link?

Comment: @Stanislav: You can't really "prove" something doesn't exist, unless you look at all possibilities and rule all of them out. If you'd like a rigorous proof, then you'd have to read the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) and see that there is no way to do this, and hence this is impossible... otherwise, though, you'll have to "take my word for it". :)

Comment: Yep, I thought you might have a specific paragraph from the standard in mind that prohibits aliasing array types. Let's wait for Jon Skeet to answer, he knows the standard by heart.

Comment: @Stanislav: Okay, here's something from the standard; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 9):

You could define a class (or struct) called ResourceMessageParamsType and define implicit operators for casting to and from object[].

```
struct ResourceMessageParamsType
{
    private object[] value;

    private ResourceMessageParamsType(object[] value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator object[](ResourceMessageParamsType t)
    {
        return t.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ResourceMessageParamsType(object[] value)
    {
        return new ResourceMessageParamsType(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasn't `implicit` meant to be `explicit`?

Comment: @sasha.sochka No, the `implicit operator` allows for implicit conversions without an explicit C-style cast operator, so you can do `ResourceMessageParamsType t = ...; object[] asArray = t;` and vice-versa: `object[] asArray = new[] { ... }; ResourceMessageParamsType t = asArray;`. (I love C#'s `implicit` operator, it's great for QoL (looking at you, Java), but it's limited in many ways, e.g. you can't have conversions (either `implicit` or `explicit`) to/from interface types, and you can't define a conversion between types that you don't control (which annoys me when working with bad libs).

Answer (score 0):

I would just derive my type from System.Array. If I'm interpreting this correctly What you are describing is a non-OO approach like you would use in plain C.

Update- I guess you can't subclass System.Array. Maybe there is a way around it.

Comment: Well, it may not be a classic OO approach, but there is a language feature of aliasing a type, "using MyType = SomeLongNameSpace.SomeType;" would work just fine, but not for arrays. What I'm trying to to is to safeguard serialization code against possible changes in class definition.

Comment: @StanislavKniazev How is a `using` alias statement going to "safeguard serialization code against possible changes in class definition"?

Comment: @Dai I don't quite remember the details from over 10 years ago, but this had to do with the fact that some of the C# code was not written by hand, but generated by a templated script. This script is not aware of c# types and if you changed it at one place and forgot to change everywhere else everything breaks sometimes subtly and unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using ResourceMessageParamsType = System.Array;
```

Not that I pretend to understand how this "safeguard[s] serialization code against possible changes in class definition" for you.

Interfaces would be a cleaner approach, and have you considered generics?

IMO Comprehensive Unit tests will ensure that if someone changes the aliased type, that all deserialization code still works.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping in a managed `struct` as user541686 rightly mentions, creates another level of indirection to what is ultimately *still* a managed array. You can alternatively use a `fixed` buffer in an `unsafe struct` to have it allocated all-in-one under your preferred typename:

```
public unsafe struct MyPreferredTypeName
{
    public fixed int buffer[256];
    //Further dereferencing not req'd: this memory is allocated inline in the struct.
}
```

However you then have no choice but to use `unsafe` blocks in your code that uses the `struct` (and if I recall correctly, also `fixed` blocks depending on your version of C#, I think < 9.0).

```
    public void MyMethod(MyPreferredTypeName data) //you can alternatively use unsafe in this line
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (MyPreferredTypeName* dataPtr = data)
            {
                dataPtr[6] = 79; //etc
            }
        }
    }
```